# ubuntu iso sha256 checksum

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, iso, hashsum

I've been having some troubles with my newly installed Ubuntu system (random freezing) and I wanted to verify that the iso I received was not corrupted by checking the sha256 hashes (I know I should have done that first).  I followed the instruction on the Ubuntu website but I keep getting the same warning, shown below:

```
user@user-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/ubuntu_isos$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.img: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.img: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.img: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.img: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso: FAILED open or read
ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.img: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.img: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.img: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.img: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: WARNING: 11 listed files could not be read
```

To let you know what I've done, I downloaded the Ubuntu desktop iso and the SHA256SUMS/SHA256SUMS.gpg files from http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ into the same directory.  I then ran the command `sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS` from this directory to get the output.  I have downloaded 5 different images and they all give this same exact output, that does not seem correct to me.  I did exactly as instructed on the Ubuntu website, but I must be doing something wrong, right?

Comment: Freezing is a normal behavior of ubuntu, don't worry! :->

Comment: @rf22: you can try using the `--ignore-missing` option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important line here is this one:

```
ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

Your ISO is OK.

The checksum file contains sums for all the images; `sha256sum` warns you about the ones you haven't downloaded, because it can't verify them.